# How to resize images in a flex container when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page displaying a few movie covers and on a large display they display well, however as the browser window is reduced I want the images to resize themselves in width (and height proportionally) until a certain size before wrapping happens.

To see what I mean exactly, check out: http://www.samuelgoldwynfilms.com/films I want the same behavior.

This is the sample I created.

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
}


.box {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-flex.css">
  <title>Learn Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box box-1">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box box-2">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71VDlRubWtL._AC_SY741_.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box box-3">
      <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box box-4">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b5/46/7f/b5467f2221d78d204b5a44c8d57d516f.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

At this stage, flexbox only performs wrapping on the items without trying to reduce them to a certain size before wrapping.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: [check this code pen](https://codepen.io/sayog/pen/LYbabba) .IS this what you want??

Comment: Not exactly. The initial size of each cover image is `width: 400px height: 600px;` now as I reduce the browser window I want the `width` and `height` to be reduced proportionally, and let's say when `width` arrives at `200px` then to wrap the items on multiple lines. If you check the link I included in my post you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you give **.box {height: 500px;}** but not width it becomes uncontrollable. For the responsive image, I suggest you use img with **max-width:100%** and **height: auto**. When you do this image resize itself based on its parent div and if you give whatever size you want to the parent div you can manipulate it easier.
So here the code;

```
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex:0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 500px;
}


.box {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box {
  margin: 10px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:520px) {
  
  .box {
   margin: auto;
  }
}
```

I am also adding the codepen code: https://codepen.io/ates_irem/pen/zYobMQr?editors=1100